# React Native tool to track re-renders visually?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have complex views with lots of components. I would like to optimise performance, I suspect that some parts of the application are being re-rendered for no reason, but I cannot see visually which ones are the problem. Is there a tool that will show me visually which parts of the screen re-rendered on state change as I'm using the app?

Comment: btw, I think I saw a project that did this a while ago for react for the web, but I can't remember the name of the project :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it finally, https://github.com/redsunsoft/react-render-visualizer. Also there is another tool, https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render, but it just logs to the console the components that rerendered and they shouldn't have. But still, a useful tool.

Comment: Here is a decorator/higher order function version: https://github.com/marcin-mazurek/react-render-debugger

Comment: and nvm it has a dependency (react-dom) that doesn't work on react-native

Answer (score 0):

Updated links for year 2020:

- [react-render-debugger](https://github.com/marcin-mazurek/react-render-debugger) by marcin-mazurek
- [why-did-you-render](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render) by welldone-software

Comment: The question was for react native, react-render-debugger is web only

Answer (score 0):

Try [heat-map-view](https://github.com/ExodusMovement/heat-map-view), a visual tool that paints the screen more and more red when re-render happens.